# Why razorpay payment gateway showing this error?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hello guys i am using razorpay payment gateway when i click on order now button this error popup.

**Oops! Something went wrong.
Invalid amount (should be passed in integer paise. Minimum value is 100 paise, i.e. ₹ 1)**

I am using HTML , JAVASCRIPT , PHP technology please give me solution for this error.

thanks in advance.

### cart code

```
     <section id="" class="container-fluid cart" style="margin-left:20px;" >
             <article id="" class="col">
                 <span class="open-modal">
                     <i id="carts" class="fa fa-shopping-cart" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#cart" style="font-size:25px"></i>
                 </span>
                 
             </article>
         </section>

     <section id="" class="container-fluid">
         <article id="" class="row">
              <div id="mask"></div>
                 <div class="modal fade" id="cart" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
               <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                 <div class="modal-content">
                   <div class="modal-header">
                     <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Cart</h5>
                   </div>
                        <form name="contactform" method="post" action="sendjs.php">    
     <div class="modal-body">

     <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 order-md-4 mb-6">

 <table id="cartents" class="show-cart table">

     </table>
    <div>Total price: <span class="total-cart" id="cartContent"></span></div>
<br>
    <div class="modal-footer">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <a href="payscript.php" ><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Order now</button></a>


    </div>
</div>
        <div class="col-md-6 order-md-1">
          <h4 class="mb-3">Billing address</h4>
          <form class = "needs-validation" novalidate>
            
             <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="fullname">Full name</label>
              <div class="input-group">

                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter your full name" required>
                <div class="invalid-feedback" style="width: 100%;">
                  Your full name is required.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        
            

            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="username">Phone no.</label>
              <div class="input-group">

                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phonenumber" placeholder="Enter your phone no." required>
                <div class="invalid-feedback" style="width: 100%;">
                  Your Phone no. is required.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="email">Email</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email">
              <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Please enter a valid email address for shipping updates.
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="mb-3">
              <label for="address">Address</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" placeholder="Enter your address" required>
              <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Please enter your shipping address.
              </div>
            </div>

  
  </div>
 </div>
</form> 
                  
         </article>
     </section>
```

### payscript.php code

```
    <?php

 $apiKey = "";

?>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>



<form action="" method="POST">
<script
    src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"
    data-key="<?php echo $apiKey; ?>" // Enter the Test API Key ID generated from Dashboard → Settings → API Keys
    data-amount="<?php echo $_POST['cartContent'] * 100;?>" // Amount is in currency subunits. Hence, 29935 refers to 29935 paise or ₹299.35.
    data-currency="INR"//You can accept international payments by changing the currency code. Contact our Support Team to enable International for your account
    data-id="<?php echo 'OID'.rand(10,100).'END';?>"//Replace with the order_id generated by you in the backend.
    data-buttontext="Pay with Razorpay"
    data-name="Atharv Organics"
    
    data-description="my website name"
    data-image="logo.png"
    data-prefill.name="name"
    data-prefill.email="email"
    data-prefill.contact="phonenumber"
    data-prefill.address="address"
    data-theme.color="#F37254"
></script>
<input type="hidden" custom="Hidden Element" name="hidden">
</form>
```

### my product code

```
    <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="card" style="width: 100%; height: auto; font-family: 'Kaisei Tokumin', serif;">
      <a class="swap" href="vegetable-storage-bag.html">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="images/products/atcs41.jpg" alt="Card image cap" style="height:auto; width:100%">
      <img class="card-img-top" src="images/products/atcs41a.jpg" alt="Card image cap" style="height:auto; width:100%">
    </a>
      <div class="card-body">
        <h6 class="card-title">Vegetable storage bag</h6>
         <b><i class="fa fa-inr" aria-hidden="true"></i> &nbsp;750</b>
        <p class="card-text"><i></i></p>
        <div>
          <a href="#" data-name="Vegitable storage bag" data-price="750" class="add-to-cart btn btn-primary" style="width:100%" onclick="return myFunction()">Add to cart</a>
        </div>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Is this a JS problem or a PHP problem? What have you tried to resolve it? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

As per code, something is wrong with the following line.

```
<?php echo $_POST['cartContent'] * 100;?>
```

You need to debug and check what is the output of the above line.
it should be in integer paise. E.g: 750 Rs  then 75000